# Codeplex será desativado no dia 25/12/2017, que tal atualizarmos os links?

Tags: debate, comunidade

Ao entrar no site do [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com) notei isto:

[image: codeplex Shutdown]

Conforme o [post feito no blog de Brian Harry](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2017/03/31/shutting-down-codeplex/), o CodePlex da será completamente desativado no dia 25/12/2017, mas até outubro os projetos lá ainda serão acessíveis.

A minha sugestão é, se você possui respostas com links no CodePlex, seria interessante fazer a atualização destes links para novos locais (muitos projetos estão no Github agora).

Eu pessoalmente iria editar, mas ao buscar assim:

- [url:"*.codeplex.com"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*.codeplex.com%22)

Me retornou ~179 resultados. Para uma pessoa só creio ser muita coisa, todavia creio que com trabalho em equipe podemos atualizar rapidamente. Se quiser colaborar basta acessar o link acima e ver quais perguntas ainda estão com o link do CodePlex. Assim que me sobrar algum tempo também irei ajudar (hoje já editei 1 resposta :P)

Fico grato pela atenção e colaboração de quem participar das edições.

Comment: Na verdade ele entrará em modo *readonly* simplificado, só pra downloads do conteúdo, mas atualizar para um GitHub ou outro lugar sempre que possível seria legal.

Comment: @bigown ou eu li errado ou entendi errado: > So, it’s time to say goodbye to CodePlex.  As of this post, we’ve disabled the ability to create new CodePlex projects.  In October, we’ll set CodePlex to read-only, before shutting it down completely on December 15th, 2017.

Comment: Internamente a Microsoft está codificando para manter ativo mesmo depois, só que não será mais o site atual, só uma lista simples de downloads.

Comment: @bigown ah sim, entendi agora :)

Comment: @bigown meio que mudando de assunto, não achei um site alternativo ao officeribbon https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53760/3635 :/ ... acho que tem coisas que não terá mesmo como atualizar os links de imediato

Comment: Faz uma lista do que não achou. Farei nos meus. Depois ajudo em de terceiros.

Comment: @bigown Ah entendi (apaguei o comentário anterior), ando sem tempo, por isto mesmo fiz a postagem aqui no meta, para solicitar a colaboração da comunidade, mas se conseguir algum tempo pra ver isto depois eu vou editando e adicionando.

Comment: Então, pelo que ta escrito ele vai ser read-only soh até 15 de dezembro, depois vai fecahar completamente @GuilhermeNascimento. Acho valida a idéia de atualizar os links com o relativo do git-hub para os projetos que foram migrados. Acho que posso dar uma ajuda nos links de android e c#

Comment: @GrupoCDSInformática foi **exatamente** o que eu disse, mas o Bigown disse que haverá outro tipo de ready-only, não posso confirmar, mas ele trabalha bastante com Microsoft talvez ele esteja certo. Obrigado, se puder colaborar já ajuda.

Comment: estou fazendo umas edições aqui e me surgiu uma dúvida...as pessoas conseguem ver que edits ainda não aprovados já foram feitos?

Comment: @carla creio que só quem tem acesso a "fila de analises", no entanto se a pessoa acessar uma pergunta com edição pendente ao tentar editar estará marcado que já existe outra edição, creio eu.

Comment: Olha o gargalo na produção...to tentando ajudar mas bati o limite de 'edições pendentes'.  O que a galera do review está fazendo em pleno domingo a tarde que não estão aqui revisando?

Comment: @carla votei pra aprovar no que consegui, domingo é meio parado mesmo. PS: eu pensava que você era da staff

Comment: Curioso vc achar isso, achei que todos os staffs fossem identificados pelo losango no nome.

Comment: @carla não foi por este motivo, o tal losango eu não me recordava se existia em vosso profile ou não, eu apenas devo ter associado você a algum evento que o Gabe promoveu e acabei por pensar isto, mas ficou claro que foi confusão minha mesmo :)

Comment: Você manja como fazer uma busca levando em conta apena a versão atual das perguntas/respostas? Porque refazendo a busca ele ainda traz as perguntas/respostas corrigidas, pois provavelmente leva em conta todo o histórico.

Comment: @carla creio ser o cache que é um pouco mais "lento" de atualizar nas páginas de busca.

Comment: Alguém poderia corrigir o link desta resposta ? [Como converter uma resposta em JSON para um objeto em C#?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/706/como-converter-uma-resposta-em-json-para-um-objeto-em-c/707#707) Na hora que eu colei ficou `httphttps`, desde já agradeço e peço desculpa.

Comment: @WéllingthonM.deSouza corrigido :)

Comment: @carla depois de 2~3 dias parece que o "cache" atualizou, agora aparece 87 resultados, até ontem ainda estava 178, mesmo que já houvessem edições, não sei como o cache funciona ao certo, mas presumo que nem tudo deve ser 100% automatizado.

Comment: @Stormwind excelente, eu tenho editado algumas coisas, mas tem muitos que ainda não foram migrados e não tem como editar ainda :/ ... felizmente são apenas 3 páginas para checar, creio que até quinta terei conseguido, junto com o apoio da comunidade editar o que é possivel.

Answer (score 2):

### Nota de agradecimento adiantada

Eu revisei a maior parte das postagens que sobraram, as que ficaram eu não encontrei links que pudessem substituir, pois:

- São links de repositórios meio abandonados
- São links para postagens dentro do codeplex de problemas de épocas especificas

Quero crer que a informação do bigown sobre o tal modo *readonly* se concretize para os projetos esquecidos do codeplex possam ainda ser acessíveis.

Até o momento deixo os agradecimentos aos usuários que notei grande esforço em me ajudarem com as edições e me perdoem se esqueci de alguém:

### Carla

Creio que foi a que mais se esforçou, na verdade fez mais que o dobro de edições que eu e o Welligton

[image: perfil de carla em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

### Wéllingthon M. de Souza

Se esforçou muito também, foi de grande ajuda:

[image: perfil de Wéllingthon M. de Souza em Stack Overflow em Português, Perguntas e respostas para programadores profissionais e entusiastas]

Obrigado a vocês (e a todos que da comunidade que colaboram aonde podem), espero que a comunidade cresça mais com esse espirito de união e organização.

Parabéns Carla e Wéllingthon.

Comment: Só agora que eu vi, lembrei que talvez ainda tinha links para atualizar rsrs. Por nada, eu gosto de ajudar pois aprendi "De graça recebeste de graça dai", como está no meu perfil, não tenho curso e nem sou formado e pela foto do meu perfil nota-se que nem na área eu trabalho rs, então tudo que eu aprendo eu também compartilho, e estou aprendendo muito aqui.

Comment: E eu só vi agora. Foi nada. Aliás, só cheguei aqui porque resolvi fazer uma segunda rodada de migração, pois já há alguns projetos que não tinham migrado que migraram agora.